# Question regarding a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning some basic commutative algebra at the moment and I am stuck at showing the
following.
Suppose $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n ) \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and that
$f(a_1, \ldots, a_n )=0$ for some $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}$.
Does it follow that $f \in (x_1 - a_1, \ldots, x_n-a_n )$? I think it does, but
could someone please show me how to prove this?

Comment: @TroyWoo well, everyone makes mistakes right? :) anyways thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. For $n=1$, $f=(x_1-a_1)q+r$ where $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder. But $f(a_1)=0$, so the remainder $r$ is $0$, and therefore $f\in\langle x_1-a_1\rangle$. For $n>1$, use induction.

In fact, the induction is quite involved. In particular, several isomorphism theorems are involved. It is best you read it through yourself. A good source of information could be Kleiman and Altman's [A Term of Commutative Algebra](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/12Nts-2up.pdf). Look for (1.9) and its proof in the solution.